# values are changing in tableview cell when scrolling and i used prototype cell in tableview. my code is below

Tags: swift

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! ViewAllCell


        stringClassObj = stringClassArray[indexPath.row]

        cell.modelNameLbl.text =  stringClassObj.model
        cell.brandLbl.text = stringClassObj.vehicleTitle
        cell.fuelTypeLbl.text = stringClassObj.fuelType
        cell.priceLbl.text = stringClassObj.Price
        cell.discountLbl.text = "5%"

        let URLBaseString = "http://vehiclebuzzzz.com/"

        let url = URL(string:URLBaseString .appending(stringClassObj.vehicleImage!))

        DispatchQueue.global().async
            {
                let dataurl = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
                DispatchQueue.main.async
                    {
                        cell.productImageView.image = UIImage(data: dataurl!)

                }
                self.tableViewObj.reloadData()

        }

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: **self.tableViewObj.reloadData()** why do you call this within the image loading method

Comment: is calling before returning cell is appropraite

Comment: it will reload the whole tableview once again..

Comment: but it is showing nothing when i gave it before return cell

Comment: reload data should only be called when we fetch the data for the tableview

Comment: even removing that also still the problem is same

Comment: have you given a placeholder image? because it will take a few seconds to load the image..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you are loading the data in a background queue, which takes a while, and once the data is available, you update the cell (in the main thread, which is correct). But while the data has been loaded, you are scrolling the table view up and down, so the cell disappears maybe at the top and will be reused at the bottom for other data. Now the background loading has finisehd (with the image data for the old cell that has already disappeared at the top) and you update the reused cell, which should dispaly something different.

What to do:

- Dont store a reference to the UICellView in the background closure, but store the index path
- When updating in the main thread, check if the image path is still visible, then fetch the cell belonging to that path, and update it.

There is also a nice tutorial by Apple (also demonstrated on some WWDC years ago):
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: can you give me some example im new to this

Comment: @Yerra, just check the LazyTableImages example. It covers almost everything you want, including stopping the download of data that isn't needed any more. I think it would be a good training to just try to understand the solution of Apple, and maybe translate it to Swift (and put it on github). I also could do this, if you got stuck, but not before this evening (german time zone).

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

Create a UIImageView extension

```
extension UIImageView {
public func imageFromServerURL(urlString: URL) {

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlString, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            print(error as Any)
            return
        }
        OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
            let image = UIImage(data: data!)
            self.image = image
        }

     }).resume()
  }
}
```

And Update `cellForRowAt` like below -

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! ViewAllCell


    stringClassObj = stringClassArray[indexPath.row]

    cell.modelNameLbl.text =  stringClassObj.model
    cell.brandLbl.text = stringClassObj.vehicleTitle
    cell.fuelTypeLbl.text = stringClassObj.fuelType
    cell.priceLbl.text = stringClassObj.Price
    cell.discountLbl.text = "5%"

     let URLBaseString = "http://vehiclebuzzzz.com/"
     let url = URL(string:URLBaseString .appending(stringClassObj.vehicleImage!))

    cell. productImageView.imageFromServerURL(urlString: url!)
    return cell
}
```

Also add `prepareForReuse' method within your custom cell class -

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
   //here set all control values to nil like below
   self.productImageView.image = nil
}
```

Hope it will work :)

Comment: this is a tricky idea! But for this special case, it has a litte drawback: If you have many cells and are scrolling fast, it will just continue loading data that has already been scrolled "out of sight", so there is no way of stopping the download for invisible cells. The Apple solution (from my answer) will stop the download for cells that have become invisible.